# Can I run gpg-agent as a regular user on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, gpg-agent

Can I start gpg-agent as a non-root user on Fedora (or RHEL or CentOS)?

If I run 'gpg-agent' it says "no gpg-agent running in this session"

Answer (score 2):

That was fairly simple. Run

```
gpg-agent --daemon
```

Any password prompts will pop up in the terminal where you started gpg-agent, not the terminal where you ran the command that needs the password.